# Assemblies Visual Studio 2010 using in monodevelop with monotouch

Tags: c#, visual-studio, assemblies, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm new in monodevelop and I have a question.
I have some assemblies developed in Visual Studio 2010 in C# and I would like to use them with monotouch in Mac, my question is: do I have to use the source and generate the assemblies with monodevelop in Mac or just I need the assemblies and add them to my solution as a reference?

Answer (score 2):

The framework profile used by MonoTouch was originally based on the Silverlight profile (aka 2.1) and was updated to include some, but not all, of the new API provided by the .NET framework 4.0.

As such you *might* be able to reuse assemblies, without recompiling them. That will depends if all the API are available, if you refer to assemblies not available in MonoTouch, under what profile (3.5 or 4.0) you're building the code...

However things would be a lot **easier** if you have the source code and are able to re-compile it inside MonoDevelop. That would provide you with debugging symbols (the .mdb files) also also catch, at compile time (not at run time), and fix code using any missing API (from MonoTouch).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the same assemblies as they are (no need for a recompile). If the assemblies depend on other nonstandard assemblies it might get tricky and you may have to deploy other assemblies along side the ones you want and then that may cause it's own problems if they are not open source or licenses are required to redistribute, etc.. Give it a shot, see what happens.